# Substring function in vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

How can I use `substr()` on objects in vector of strings?

```
vector<string>text[7];
for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
{
   for (int y=0;y <text[i].size(); y++)
   {
       text[j][y].substr(1,1);
   }
}
```

Comment: `substr` returns a `string`..

Comment: @herohuyongtao Did you read whole post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change

   ```
   for (int y=0;y <text[i].size(); i++)
   ```

   to

   ```
   for (int y=0; y<text[j].size(); j++) // as no "i" here
   ```
2. `substr()` will return a `string`, so you probably need to use a `string` to receive its return value (although can still compile successfully if not), otherwise, it's meaningless to do `substr()` here.

   ```
   string str = text[j][y].substr(1,1);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
   for (int y=0;y <text[i].size(); i++)
```

Try increasing `y` instead of `i`

```
   for (int y=0;y <text[i].size(); y++)
```

Normally, people uses `i,j,k,l` for nested loops. But if you like y, you should increase it.

Comment: i instead of y was my small mistake, but the function still doesn't work

Comment: @AirelleJab You should assign the result of `substr`.

Comment: you will need a lvalue to make `text[j][y].substr(1,1);` have some effect